# build numba from source on Windows 64x machine

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, numba, building

I'm trying to build build NUMBA package form its source to generate a wheel out of it. I know there is a wheel for windows but I want to do some test on my local Windows 64X machine. I have installed  NUMPY, LLVMLITE dependencies and I'm using MinGW c++ compiler and not visual studio. I get a below error, what am I missing here?

```
py : C:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: 
UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ py setup.py bdist_wheel 2>&1 > error.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Workspace\Py...tuptools first.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

warnings.warn(TBB not found Using OpenMP from: True running bdist_wheel running build got version from file C:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\numba-0.54.1\numba/_version.py {'version': '0.54.1', 'full': '39aef3deb073a67b0bf121e099ecf5b33d799f40'}
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'numba._dispatcher' extension
C compiler: gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

compile options: '-D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1927 - 
IC:\\Workspace\\Python_Runtime\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include - 
IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -c'
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1927 - 
IC:\\Workspace\\Python_Runtime\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include - 
IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -c 
numba/_dispatcher.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\_dispatcher.o
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1927 - 
IC:\\Workspace\\Python_Runtime\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include - 
IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -c numba/_hashtable.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\_hashtable.o
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1927 - 
IC:\\Workspace\\Python_Runtime\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include - 
IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -c numba/core/typeconv/typeconv.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64 3.9\Release\numba\core\typeconv\typeconv.o
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x1927 - 
IC:\\Workspace\\Python_Runtime\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include - 
IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -IC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\include -c numba/_typeof.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\_typeof.o
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
numba/_hashtable.c:102:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_hash_int' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
_Numba_hashtable_hash_int(const void *key)
^
numba/_hashtable.c:108:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_hash_ptr' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_hash_ptr(const void *key)
 ^
  numba/_hashtable.c:114:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_compare_direct' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_compare_direct(const void *key, const _Numba_hashtable_entry_t *entry)
 ^
 numba/_hashtable.c:133:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_new_full' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_new_full(size_t data_size, size_t init_size,
 ^
  numba/_hashtable.c:178:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_new' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_new(size_t data_size,
 ^
  numba/_hashtable.c:188:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_size' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_size(_Numba_hashtable_t *ht)
 ^
 numba/_hashtable.c:259:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_get_entry' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_get_entry(_Numba_hashtable_t *ht, const void *key)
 ^
 numba/_hashtable.c:312:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_set' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
  _Numba_hashtable_set(_Numba_hashtable_t *ht, const void *key,
  ^
 numba/_hashtable.c:354:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_get' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_get(_Numba_hashtable_t *ht, const void *key, void *data, size_t data_size)
 ^
 numba/_hashtable.c:368:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_pop' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
_Numba_hashtable_pop(_Numba_hashtable_t *ht, const void *key, void *data, size_t data_size)
^
numba/_hashtable.c:377:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_delete' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_delete(_Numba_hashtable_t *ht, const void *key)
 ^
 numba/_hashtable.c:391:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_foreach' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_foreach(_Numba_hashtable_t *ht,
 ^
 numba/_hashtable.c:451:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_clear' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_clear(_Numba_hashtable_t *ht)
 ^
 numba/_hashtable.c:470:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_destroy' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_destroy(_Numba_hashtable_t *ht)
 ^
 numba/_hashtable.c:491:1: warning: '_Numba_hashtable_copy' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 _Numba_hashtable_copy(_Numba_hashtable_t *src)
 ^
  In file included from C:/Program Files/R/Rtools/mingw_64/x86_64-w64 mingw32/include/c++/cassert:43:0,
             from numba/_dispatcher.cpp:5:
  numba/_dispatcher.cpp: In function 'PyObject* call_cfunc(Dispatcher*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)':
  numba/_dispatcher.cpp:383:41: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '|' [-Wparentheses]
  assert(PyCFunction_GET_FLAGS(cfunc) == METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS);
                                     ^
  g++ -g -shared build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\_dispatcher.o build\temp.win-amd64 3.9\Release\numba\_hashtable.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\_typeof.o build\temp.win amd64-3.9\Release\numba\core\typeconv\typeconv.o - 
  LC:\\Workspace\\Python_Runtime\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\lib - 
  LC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\libs -LC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\PCbuild\amd64 -lnpymath -lpython39 -o build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\numba\_dispatcher.cp39-win_amd64.pyd build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\_typeof.o: In function `typecode_using_fingerprint': C:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\numba-0.54.1/numba/_typeof.c:617: undefined reference to `__imp__Numba_hashtable_get'
 C:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\numba-0.54.1/numba/_typeof.c:639: undefined reference to `__imp__Numba_hashtable_set' build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\_typeof.o: In function `typeof_init':
  C:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\numba-0.54.1/numba/_typeof.c:1115: undefined reference to `__imp__Numba_hashtable_new'
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: Command "g++ -g -shared build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\_dispatcher.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\_hashtable.o build\temp.win-amd64 3.9\Release\numba\_typeof.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\numba\core\typeconv\typeconv.o 
  -LC:\\Workspace\\Python_Runtime\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\lib - 
   LC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\libs -LC:\Workspace\Python_Runtime\Python\PCbuild\amd64 -lnpymath -lpython39 -o build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\numba\_dispatcher.cp39-win_amd64.pyd" failed with 
 exit status 1
```

Comment: IIRC cpython is only supported for MSVC on windows. The warning tells, that something went wrong with defines for function visibility. It is much easier to use the supported tool chain - there will be quite some subtle surprises if you don’t.